# How to cancel delivery in clearcase

Tags: clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I want to cancel (undo) a delivery in Clearcase for my Dev stream but it gives below error :

```
"unable to cancel delivery because another operation is trying to complete it"
```

What can be the possible cause and resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using an old ClearCase 7.0 ([whic has a fix to avoid that error](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PK84178)), that can happen when the [deliver was started *twice*](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/starting-ucm-deliver-twice-windows-gui-results-stuck-deliver)

The exact error message is:

```
cleartool deliver -cancel
Cancel deliver
FROM: stream "<source-stream>"
TO: stream "<target-stream>"
Using target view: "<target-view>".
Are you sure you want to cancel this deliver operation?  [no] yes
cleartool: Error: Unable to cancel delivery because another operation is trying to complete.
cleartool: Error: Unable to cancel deliver.
```

("trying to complete", no "it" at the end)

> Attempting to start a deliver twice in the Windows GUI results in a stuck deliver operation.
>
> This is applicable when using UCM with ClearQuest (CQ) integration and having the ClearQuest policy, Transition To Complete After Delivery, enabled.
>
> The CQ policy, Transition To Complete After Delivery, tries to transition the activities to complete, but cannot find any.
> This causes the `deliver -complete` to fail.

More generally, check your OS processes to determine if another process keep an handle which would prevent any cancellation.